# How to set logging level in a unit test for Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am running a particular unit test in my library, and I would like to get more logging from it. I am running it in the following way:

```
python -m unittest my_module.my_submodule_test.MyTestClass.test_my_testcase
```

Because I'm doing this, the `my_submodule_test.py` file does not run the bottom part where I set the log level like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  unittest.main()
```

How can I programatically set the log level so that I can get more detailed logging from my test?

Also, I'd like to be able to set the logging via a command-line argument. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change log level in unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315180/change-log-level-in-unittest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way in which this can be done is by doing it in the `setUp` code of your `TestCase` subclass. You would do the following:

```
class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

You can use either `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`, or `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.

This should activate logging for your whole project (unless you are changing the level for loggers further down in the hierarchy that you care about).

I do not know of a way to do this from the command line, unfortunately.